# Java 11 Linux VM cpu memory not coming down until we restart application

Tags: java, java-11

Recently we upgraded the java version from 8 to 11. Whenever the application processing a high load of data, CPU and memory reach maximum >90%. Still, after the load got reduced, the CPU/Memory is not getting down until we restart the application.

I have these parameters

```
APP_JVM_XMS=256M
APP_JVM_XMX=4096M
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. What does your application does? have you found any memory leak? We can't do nothing with this kind of information

Comment: As @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo already mentioned, we need more information to help you. It could be anything, memory leak, dependable resources, etc. Try enabling [Garbage Collection](https://baeldung.com/java-verbose-gc) logs to identify the issue.

Comment: Depending on the garbage collector used, memory is not returned to the OS until application exit, so it remains in use. For example, ShenandoahGC will release memory back if it hasn't been used for - by default - 5 minutes. AFAIK, the default collectors in Java 11 (and Java 8 for that matter) which are used when no collector has been explicitly configured, do not release memory back to the OS. However, defaults have changed compared to Java 8, so possibly the results in higher CPU and memory requirements. You may want to look at tuning and configuring the garbage collector.